# Understanding async behaviour of C# console TCP server

Tags: c#, tcp, server, async-await, .net-core

I want to create a simple TCP server in .NET Core 2.0 using asynchrony (because from what I understand, it's more reasonable than spawning threads) with the `async/await` approach (because I believe it's more up-to-date than the one with `IAsyncResult` and `*Begin/*End` methods).

I've written this small server that accepts new connections from clients and then begins to send them 100 messages (with a 1s delay between them).

The main question is:

*If I'm not spawning new threads, then how the server continues to send delayed messages to several clients, when in fact it's "waiting for connection"*? *Are there any hidden low-level signals/events involved, or are there really just new threads?*

The second question is:

*If I'm not using this brand new `async Main` syntax sugar and I'm not "awaiting" the `async` task of sending the messages -- am I using the asynchrony correctly?*

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StartServer();
    }

    public static void StartServer()
    {
        IPAddress localhost = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localhost, 5567);

        Console.WriteLine($"Starting listening on {listener.Server.LocalEndPoint}");
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
            var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); // synchronous
            Console.WriteLine($"Connected with {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}!");

            Console.WriteLine("Starting sending messages...");
            SendHundredMessages(client); // not awaited -- StartServer is not async
        }
    }


    public static async Task SendHundredMessages(TcpClient client)
    {
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Message no #{i}\n");
            await stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);    // returning back to caller?

            await Task.Delay(1000);     // and what about here?
        }
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

*What is the difference between the original code and the version below? What difference does `async Main` make?*

```
class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await StartServer();
    }

    public static async Task StartServer()
    {
        IPAddress localhost = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(localhost, 5567);

        Console.WriteLine($"Starting listening on {listener.Server.LocalEndPoint}");
        listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection...");
            var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(); // does it make any difference when done asynchronously?
            Console.WriteLine($"Connected with {client.Client.RemoteEndPoint}!");

            Console.WriteLine("Starting sending messages...");
            SendHundredMessages(client); // cannot await here, because it blocks next connections
        }
    }


    public static async Task SendHundredMessages(TcpClient client)
    {
        var stream = client.GetStream();

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
        {
            var msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"Message no #{i}\n");
            var result = stream.WriteAsync(msg, 0, msg.Length);

            await Task.Delay(1000);
            await result;
        }
        client.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is `StartServer` `async Task` if you aren't `await`ing anything? You should at least use `await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();`

Comment: Because I earlier tried to `await StartServer()`  in `async Main` and (after failure) I forgot to change the type of this method back to void.

Comment: If I `await` the `AcceptTcpClientAsync()` without changing `void Main` to `async Task Main` and `StartServer();` to `await StartServer();` then the program ends there.

On the other hand -- what is the purpose of awaiting _Accept_ when the caller is just this almost empty Main method?

Comment: Because `AcceptTcpClient` is an I/O bounded method (like `stream.WriteAsync`), hence a truly asynchronous method, and it benefits the most from asynchronous code. Who calls it doesn't really matter. You should block `StartServer` on `Main` and leave it as `async Task`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I edited the original code (the type of StartServer that you mentioned). I also added a follow-up question just before you added your comment. What is the benefit of _Accept_ being async if the server does nothing else at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The answer to the main question:**

In the background, as a rule, objects work with some api(winapi for windows). These api can implement asynchrony differently. For example, events(winapi events) or callbacks. So the answer is yes - there are hidden signals or threads. For example, you can see the **Ping** class. `Ping.InternalSend` using `ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` for the task of asynchrony.

**The answer about async Main:**

In your first code because `StartServer` is not async the `Main` method will not get back control until your "accept" cycle ends.

In your second code, the `Main` method will get back control then `listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync` invoked. But because you using `await StartServer();` the Main method will be wait until `StartServer` ends.

Some code for to explain:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {   
            // not await for exploration
            var task = StartServer();

            Console.WriteLine("Main StartServer finished");
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("task.Wait() finished");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }        

        static async Task StartServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StartServer enter");

            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                await Task.Delay(1000); // listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync simulation
                SendHundredMessages();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("StartServer exit");
        }

        static async Task SendHundredMessages()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SendHundredMessages enter");

            await Task.Run(() => {
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            });

            Console.WriteLine("SendHundredMessages exit");
        }        
    }
}
```

This code generate this output:

> StartServer enter
>   Main StartServer finished
>   SendHundredMessages enter
>   SendHundredMessages enter
>   SendHundredMessages exit
>   SendHundredMessages enter
>   StartServer exit
>   task.Wait() finished
>   SendHundredMessages exit
>   SendHundredMessages exit

As you can see, the `Main` method continued execution right after first `Task.Delay`.

**A warning:**

You do not wait end of `SendHundredMessages`, and this is very bad. In example output you can see that "*SendHundredMessages ending*" after "*task.Wait() finished*". In example application of course it not danger, but in real project you can get big problem.